SQL trigger to trip only on update of most recent version of order
Scenario: I have an order system with an order_header and an order_stage table.
The orders can have multiple stages, but only one, the highest stage, is active at any one time.
I want to create a trigger that trips and inserts shipping tracking numbers when only the highest (Max) stage is updated. Additionally, I only want to insert these records IF the tracking number is not already in the 2nd table.
IF (UPDATE (trackingID)) 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    INSERT INTO Ship_Notifications (OrderID, Tracker, email, Address1, City, Prov, Postal, ShipDate)
        SELECT 
            I.OrderID, I.TrackingID, sc.Email, 
            I.Address2, I.Address3, I.Address4, I.Address5, GETDATE()
        FROM 
            INSERTED I
        JOIN 
            order_header oh ON I.OrderID = oh.OrderID
        JOIN 
            surgeon_contacts sc ON sc.SurgeonID = oh.SurgeonID
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Ship_Notifications SN 
                        WHERE SN.Tracker = I.TrackingID);
END

This trigger works and adds the information I need, but the system I am working with runs an update on the order_stage table even if the order wasn't modified but someone clicked the save button. Also, every column is defined as Not Null, and therefore all columns are updated on that save (I realize that because all columns get updated, I don't really need the IF (UPDATE (trackingID)) check).
Thus I need to only trigger or pull in the info from the record with the highest stageID value which is an integer.
The order stage table where the information comes from:

The Ship_Notifications table that is used to insert the updated tracking numbers from the Trigger:

I have truncated the data for privacy.

Sample data and expected results are essential. Please also show DDL definitions for all tables.

Triggers are highly vendor-specific - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.

@Charlieface I've added some sample data, hopefully that helps.

Please don't use images for data, use table markdown

It's bit unclear to me what you are specifically stuck on? If you can write a query to identify the latest Id per order_stage you can use that to filter your trigger?

No that doesn't help I can't copy it because it's an image, and I don't understand your intended result. Please add all the info I asked for, as text not images. Proper CREATE TABLE DDL would help even more.

I may have created a solution or at least a workaround to my issue by ignoring anything prior to a certain date, say, Dec 1 2024.
As per @DaleK 's comment, I can write a query to find the identify the latest StageID, but I believe that requires me to use a Parameter (using the OrderID), in which I don't know how to implement in a Trigger.

What would you need a parameter for? A joined sub-query should do what you need

As I understand the INSERTED table, it can have multiple records in it at the same time, I reckon my query would need to reference an OrderID in order to get the MAX(StageID) for that order. Hence the parameter I thought I needed. Clearly I'm overlooking something. Given the table referenced can someone suggest such a sub-query?

You're thinking correctly, probably you need to check so inserted.StageId is same as the maximum stageID in your OrderHeader-table, using where exists or other means.
